# How to do cross namespace communication using a local sub domain in local k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to make my authentication service accessible using local domain `auth.ticketing.dev` to a Next.js web client running in the 'development' namespace. The service is currently running in the 'fusionauth' namespace and is exposed via ingress at `auth.ticketing.dev` to my system. I am running kubernetes using ranhcer desktop and ingress-nginx. Pods can access the service with the `http://service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:9011` url but not using the sub domain. NextAuthJS library is used to connect to auth server(FusionAuth).

[Here is an image of two service running in separate namespace in k8s. One service needs to communicate with the other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03JXo.png)

The auth service(FusionAuth) has following helm values for ingress

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
  ingressClassName: nginx
  paths:
    - path: /?(.*)
      pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  extraPaths: []
  hosts:
    - auth.ticketing.dev
  tls: []
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Ingress object is **namespaced** which means that it interacts with services within the **same namespace**. Also, only one ingress object per *host/domain* is allowed.

However, you have two different namespaces...I will suppose, you managed to make the ingress works and I get back to your main question:

Networking **within** a Kubernetes cluster can be done in different ways, but the recommended and most common way is to use its ***built-in DNS name***.

Pods get their own DNS names, but it is recommended that you access another app in the cluster via the DNS name for the Service.

To send a request from `development` namespace to the app in a different namespace `fusionauth`, use the namepspace part of the built-in domain name service, i.e  `<app-service-name>.fusionauth.svc.cluster.local:<port>`